# PowerShell: how can I tell if the user has access to read a secret from Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm writing a script that needs to determine if a secret exists in Key Vault. A lot of the logic of the script hangs off this fact.

The problem I'm having is that my script cannot tell the difference between the secret not existing, and the user not having access to read it.

The code I'm using to get the secret is as follows:

```
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName
```

The `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` commandlet:

1. If the secret exists and can be read, returns the secret
2. If the secret does not exist but the user is allowed read from the key vault, returns `$null`
3. If the user is not allowed to read from the key vault, returns `$null` and writes
   error text to the console

The problem is that I cannot distinguish (in code) between the latter two. The commandlet does not throw an exception and the error text doesn't appear to be written to a standard stream where I can redirect it using `Out-String` or similar.

Can anyone recommend how I might distinguish between conditions 2) and 3) above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it inside a try-catch with an `ErrorAction` Stop

```
try{
  $secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
   write-host "Cannot read secrets!"
}
```

Comment: Right! I just needed `-ErrorAction Stop`. I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 2):

About condition 2, I throw the exception when `$secret.count -eq 0`.
The status code of condition 3 is "403", so I use `$exception.Response.StatusCode.value__` to catch it.

```
$vaultName=""
$secretName=""

try{
    $secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName -ErrorAction Stop

    if($secret.count -eq 0){
        throw [Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException] "$secretName secret not found."
    }
}
catch
{
   $exception = $_.Exception
   while ($exception.GetType().FullName -eq "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException") {
      if($exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ -eq "403") {
          write-output "user is not allowed."
      } else {
          write-output "secret not found."
      }
      break
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.